# matrix as the array of arrays

Tags: arrays, delphi, function, matrix, pascal

I've a function that checks if there is a repeat data in the array; That looks like shown below. The task is using that function find the columns in matrix with no repeating data. The question is to how to pass the column of the matrix to that function.

P.S. I'm using Pascal/Delphi

```
type
  myArray = array [1..10] of integer;

function noRepeat(A: myArray; n: integer): Boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  Result := true;
  for i:=1 to n do
    for j := i + 1 to n do
      if  (A[i] = A[j]) then
        Result := true;
end;
```

Comment: in MxN matrix where M is row size and N is column size, this will give you colums: for i:=0 to n do for j:=0 to m a[i, j].

Comment: how is your matrix type definition looks like?

Comment: Pass arrays by const. Don't copy them. Use open arrays. No need to pass length explicitly, if your arrays are ro major then you'll need to pick out the column into a temp array, and pass that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the example below:

```
matrix[column][row]
```

is how the 'myMatrix' type is structured.  Just iterate through the first array and send it off to your testing function.

Also, in the testing function, make sure you set your result to false to begin with!

```
type
  myArray = array [1..10] of integer;
  myMatrix = array[1..10] of myArray;

var
  matrix: myMatrix;

function noRepeat(const A: myArray): Boolean;
var
  i: integer;
begin
  //Result := true; //?
  Result := false;
  for i:=1 to high(A) do
    for j := i + 1 to high(A) do
      if  (A[i] = A[j]) then
        Result := true;
end; 

procedure sendColumn;
var
  b, wasRepeat: boolean;
  i: Integer;
Begin

  for i := low(matrix) to high(matrix) do
  Begin
    b := noRepeat(matrix[i]);
    if b then
      wasRepeat := true;
  End;

End;
```

if it's row major, then you'll have to inform the testing routine of which column you want to test.

```
type
  myArray = array [1..10] of integer;
  myMatrix = array[1..10] of myArray;

var
  matrix: myMatrix;

function noRepeat(const A: myMatrix; Col: Integer): Boolean;
var
  i, j: integer;
begin

  Result := false;
  for i := low(A) to high(A) do      
    for j := i + low(A) to high(A) do
      if  (A[i][Col] = A[j][Col]) then
        Result := true;
end; 

procedure sendColumn;
var
  b, wasRepeat: boolean;
  i: Integer;
Begin

  for i := 1 to 10 do
  Begin
    b := noRepeat(matrix, i);
    if b then
      wasRepeat := true;
  End;

End;
```

Comment: thx a lot, but ur code sends to noRepeat function the rows, but not the columns of the matrix

Comment: Whether you decide that the arrays will be sorted as [Column][Row] or [Row][Column] is entirely up to you.  It's essentially the same structure.

Comment: What @user means is this his/her arrays are row major.

Comment: added example for row major matrices.

Comment: guess i understood ur explanation, but noRepeat must take the Array type - that is said in the task

Comment: It's the same concept, but you'll have to do the math in your arrays, if you want to use a one-dimensional structure. [RowToCheck*AmountOfColumns+ColumnToCheck]

Comment: i have to use two dimmential array in the "main" program

Comment: @user If you have a 2D array, you don't have 1D arrays representing both rows and columns. So if you are row major then you need to pick out the columns one way or another. This seems like a good answer to me. If there's a problem it's in the question which doesn't even show your matrix type leaving us to guess. Try harder.